# VBA Question about Set same value and finding the same value

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking at some VBA code but I am confused about this line.

`Set rngLookup = CurrWPWkSht.Columns("A").Find(rngLookup, lookat:=xlPart)`

Does this line mean that the code is finding rngLookup in column A and setting it in the same variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not really**

So `rngLookup` should be a range variable. Using a range, the default interpretation is `Range.Value`, so if you say `Msgbox Range("A")` that would return the same as `Msgbox Range("A").value`

```
Set rngLookup = CurrWPWkSht.Columns("A").Find(rngLookup.value, lookat:=xlPart)
```

Should work the same.
It's not uncommon to use a variable to change the same variable, as for a counter type variable: `i = i + 1`

In this case we are searching for the value in the range specified in `rngLookup`, and then set the result of the search as the new range for the variable, replacing the old range.

[.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) returns a range, hence the `set` and the fact that `rngLookup` is a range variable. And while the range stored in the variable has a `.value` property the variable stores the whole range, with all range properties.

**So**
We're not really searching for a value and then setting it to that same value.
We're searching for a value, and then setting it to the range where the value was found.